# Linode Private IPs

Tags: linode, private-ip

I'm trying to get private IPs set up with my Linodes. I'm running Debian. Here's my Linode's Network tab:

```
eth0:            69.164.214.146
                 ( li129-146.members.linode.com )
Gateways:        69.164.214.1
Netmask:         255.255.255.0
Private eth0:    192.168.140.217
Netmask:         255.255.128.0
DNS Servers:     97.107.133.4
                 207.192.69.4
                 207.192.69.5
```

and here's my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 eth0:0
iface eth0 inet static
 address 69.164.214.146
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 69.164.214.1

iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 192.168.140.217
 netmask 255.255.128.0
```

On the linode I'm setting up, I can `ping 192.168.140.217` just fine. The other linode will not, though.

Yes, the other Linode is in the same data center.

Perhaps there is something I need to do with `iptables`? Perhaps my configuration isn't right? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you restarted your linode since adding the private IP? If that doesn't work just send in a support ticket - the linode staff are great and they'll get this working for you in no time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was that both Linodes require the private IP address to be installed. Having only one ruptured the space-time continuum and disturbed life as we know it.